# strange string error

Tags: c++

**program:**

```
 CCompussGradientOperator dlg;
  string p = "preqitt";
  string k = "Kirnch";
  string r3 = "Robison";
  f(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
      {
    CDib dib = m_Dib;
    BOOL ret = FALSE;

    if(dlg.m_Combo_Operators == p )
    {
       switch(dlg.m_nFunction)
       {
       case 0: ret ;
       }
    }

}
```

**error**:

Error   18  error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier   d:\2nd\imagetool\imagetooldoc.cpp   870 1   ImageTool

string is a data type then why it does make me error.. its strange for me...
any one can help me ..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you included `<string>` header ? Also it is in namespace `std`.

Comment: but i included header file.. even then i am getting same error .. why?

Comment: @Miss - `string` is in `std` namespace. So, did you place the statement after the header inclusion - `using namespace std;` ? or else you need to qualify `string` with `std::` on it's every usage as @eduffy suggested.

Comment: @Mahesh: well i did , but same error i am getting.. i maked a small program as testing .. there @eduffy suggession worked.. but in the above program, it do't work .. i am getting same errors as before..

Comment: @mahesh... silly mistake .... i add #include <string.h>  thats'y making me error ...but now its solved..

Answer (score 1):

Change `string` to `std::string`.  Also, do you have `#include <string>` at the top of the source file?

Comment: but i included header file.. even then i am getting same error .. why?

Comment: Did you do the part of my answer?

Comment: @eduffy, i have #include<string> even then i am getting error.. whats problem now?

Comment: Did you add `std::` in front of `string` yet?

Comment: strange, i did your part like std::string.. string is not in the namespace of std...same error i have as before ..:(

Comment: well @eduffy i tested as small program.. it worked but in the above program , it do't work ..